# Mavenizing Netbeans Platform Application, is this possible?

Tags: java, ant, maven, netbeans-platform

I am exploring NetBeans (7.0) Platform Application. Using the File > Create project option generates an ant based project.

Is it possible to use Maven instead? If yes, how should one proceed? Do you have a pom.xml sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search with google turns up these two articles:

- http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/04/maven.html
- http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html

Comment: I don't know how I have missed that... Thanks.